# Нужно задать матрицу n*m и заполнить её нулями, python

Tags: python

То, до чего я додумался - не работает

```
n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
field = [[0 * m] * n]
print(field)
```

ожидаю [[], [], [], []], выдаёт [[]]

Скорее всего делаю что-то не так.

Comment: `[[0] * m for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: @splash58, вроде просто умножение пишется короче. Или есть подвохи?

Comment: @splash58, а всё, сам понял. Они ж редактируемые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Умножать на количество надо список, а не элемент: https://ideone.com/y3Ox6i

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = [[0] * m] * n
print(a)
```

Только есть подвох: при умножении список дублируется по ссылке, так что менять списки по отдельности не выйдет и после

```
a[0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

получится https://ideone.com/VdKotg

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Чтобы иметь новые списки в каждом элементе, можно поступить как написал @splash58: https://ideone.com/ja4iy6

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = [[0] * m for _ in range(n)]
print(a)

a[0][0] = 1
print(a)
```

Comment: @splash58, ага, но я уже сам догадался после того, как спросил. И дополнил ответ :)

Comment: Да, написал, и увидел, что есть редакция ответа

Comment: Лучше перекинь кусочек после своего "подвоха", вместе лучше будет

Comment: @splash58, не понял, что ты предлагаешь.

Comment: Предлагаю в твоем ответе не просто написать, что будут ссылки, а заодно показать как обойти

Comment: @splash58, ну у тебя же уже есть ответ - логичнее написать в нём. Вообще надо было сразу писать не комментарий, а ответ.

Comment: “Сделайте милость, не беспокойтесь так для меня, я пройду после”, говорил Чичиков. “Нет уж извините, не допущу пройти ~ с приятною улыбкою Манилов. — “Нет, Павел Иванович, это обида. Вы хотите, чтобы я такому приятному гостю позволил пройти после себя”. “Ах, боже мой… Мне, право, совестно. Проходите, сделайте милость, проходите, я после”, говорил Чичиков. “Нет, никак нельзя”.

Comment: Есть возможность как-то обойти работу со ссылками? Где-то сделать копию?

Comment: @ArtyomLazovikov, ну вообще-то тебе в первом же комментарии ответили. Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Модуль `numpy` устроит?

```
import numpy as np
n,m=5, 7
print(np.zeros((n,m), dtype=int).tolist())

# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Вполне, спасибо)